# WGAW and DGA Penalizing George Lucas for ESB Credits

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

After letting George Lucas slide on a few slipped protocols for [A New Hope](https://www.starwars.com/films/star-wars-episode-iv-a-new-hope) (SW-ANH), the [Writers Guild of America West](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writers_Guild_of_America,_West) (WGAW) and the [Directors Guild of America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directors_Guild_of_America) (DGA) decided they needed to set heavy penalties for the way the credits in [The Empire Strikes Back](https://www.starwars.com/films/star-wars-episode-v-the-empire-strikes-back) (SW-ESB) were shown to the audience.¹

Between the two guilds, he was fined a quarter of a million dollars. Due to the controversy, he left the DGA, WGAW as well as the [Motion Picture Association](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Association_of_America).

My inquiry is simple and maybe twofold.

Did the two guilds' leadership decide to attack and penalize Lucas and Kershner as an independent action of their leadership or were these actions precipitated by one or more regular guild members registering complaints?

If it was the guilds' leadership that initiated the attacks, was any evidence of collusion between the two made public?

---

¹ <sub>To preserve the dramatic opening sequences of his films, Lucas wanted the screen credits to come only at the end. While this practice has become more common over the years, this was relatively unusual at the time. The Writers and Directors guilds of America had no problem allowing it on Star Wars, back in 1977, because the writer-director credit (George Lucas) matched the company name. However, when Lucas did the same thing for the sequel, it became an issue because they viewed the company credit (Lucasfilm) as displaying Lucas' name at the start of the film, while the director and writers had theirs on the end. The guilds fined him over $250,000 and attempted to pull Empire out of theaters. The DGA also attacked Kershner; to protect his director, Lucas paid all the fines to the guilds. Due to the controversy, he left the Directors and Writers guilds, and the Motion Picture Association. ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Empire_Strikes_Back#Filming))</sub>

Comment: As an aside the current rules state that the key members of a film (writer, director, producer and main stars) must have there own defined credits. Usually at the start of the movie, but, if shown at the end they have to be seperated out from the rolling end credits. Hence most movies (including all marvel films) now have that post film credit scene and then repeat all those same credits in the credit crawl. The director of Deadpool discuses this in the Deadpool Honest Trailer commentry https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fG2GuXbAvg